# GPS/GPRS Trackers. How to handle stored FIFO data to record total time an I/O was on or off

Tags: php, mysql, gps

I'm not sure if my question accurately describes my problem. I'll try and lay it out as best I can.

I have a number of GPS trackers installed in vehicles which report back to my server via GPRS. I have built a fully functional mysql database driven PHP website to display the vehicle location and track its history.

My next step is building a section that will show the vehicles total distance since the ignition was turned on and the total time the ignition was on.

This is working quite well by using a simple script to add the distance field in the incomming data of a device to the last stored record for that device. Likewise, the time is calculated in the same way.

However, when the device goes out of GSM coverage, the position data is stored on an SD card and, when back in GSM range, will send the current position first, then start sending the stored data, interspersed with the current position every minute.

This messes up my calculation and I start getting negative time values because of the stored data datetime field being BEFORE the last datetime record in the database.

I really would like to do this calulation on the GPS server/parser rather than on the website to allow the website to load faster. I am envisioning an extemely large database in a few years time and would like to have the totals stored in a table rather than using a script to calculate it every time the page loads.

Comment: Why don't you just store each point and then do the suming and delete them after a few days?

Comment: The problem is the device could be out of range for more than just a few days. I could wait until all the stored data has been retured by the device but I still would need some way to determine this.

Comment: You could have the device send a special message when it finishes uploading the old data. That way you will know that data before that point is complete

Comment: Or maybe have the device send an information that it has a backlog when it logs back into the network and instead of summing like usualy store the data and sum it up once the device says it finished with old data.

Comment: I have thought of that but I don't have access to the firmware source code. This would be the last resort because I would have to get hold of the manufacturer and ask them to personalise the firmware for me. I don't know how long it would take though.

Comment: Well, you just gotta do some assumption then. Can't you assume that if the device has been transimting it current position for over an hour and wasn't sendind old data that it doesn't have any backlog?